# Given bode plot, determine the poles and zeroes

Tags: stability, transfer-function, bode-plot

Ultimately, I want to figure out the transfer function $$H(s)$$

But to know that I would need to know where the poles and zeroes are.

- Looking at this, I know $$ H(20j) = 0  $$ but that's pretty much it. Where are the poles?

[image: Transfer function]

Comment: This smells like homework.

Comment: Well, nothing wrong with that. :/

Comment: What have you done to try to figure this out?

Comment: From my understanding, H(s) = (s - z)(s - z)/(s - p)(s - p).. where p are the poles, and z are the zeroes. At H(j0), which is where omega = 20 on the plot, that would be one of the zeroes, z.

Comment: There you go, now use the first few sentences of my answer, and think in 3D. The rest of the zeroes, and then the poles will become obvious.

Answer (score 2):

First, consider that zeros are values where the numerator of a transfer function equal zero. Poles are values where the denominator of a transfer function equals zero. When the numerator is zero, the output is zero. When the denominator is zero, the output shoots up to infinity, and in the case of a filter, in unstable.

Now a pole zero plot in 3D will look like this:

[image: pole-zero 3D plot]

This plot is in the complex plane. The frequency response plot can be obtained by taking the magnitude along the imaginary axis. This plot is double sided, but we only care about the positive half most of the time.

In the case of the frequency response plot you posted, I see three zeroes and two poles.  You are correct that \$H(j20)=0\$. By the the definition of a zero, that means that is a zero. I'm not going to give you any more answers until you show some effort.

Comment: Aren't there just 2 zeroes?

Comment: No, there is a third, and its interacting with the poles.